# Не работает скрипт под cron-ом

Tags: linux, debian, cron, crontab, squid

Есть скрипт, который чистит кеш SQUID. Когда он запускается сам (через crontab), то вываливаются ошибки:

```
2021/02/08 14:22:09 kid1| ERROR: /var/spool/squid/00: (2) No such file or directory
FATAL: Failed to verify one of the swap directories, Check cache.log
for details. Run 'squid -z' to create swap directories
if needed, or if running Squid for the first time.
Squid Cache (Version 3.5.23): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.036 seconds = 0.020 user + 0.016 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 110992 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
```

Вот сам скрипт, элементарный:

```
#! /bin/bash
#Очистка кеша SQUID

#останавливаем squid службу
service squid stop
#очищаем папку с кешем
rm -rf /var/spool/squid/*
#Создаём новый кеш
squid -z
#Запускаем squid службу
service squid start
```

А если я запускаю его вручную, то всё норм...
Что может быть? Я что-то подзавис...

Comment: А от имени какой учётной записи он выполняется-то?

Comment: Мама дорогая! В первую очередь, очистка кэша прокси сервера может делаться асинхронно. Во вторую, в хороших дистрибутивах это не нужно, так как кэш имеет ограниченный объём, и мало используемое всё равно вытеснится. В третью, полно уж объяснений про особенности окружения cron. В четвёртую, кто вам насоветовал вот это всё?